# $request->all() add unnecessary parameter in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, request, laravel-5.5

`reuest()->all()` add unnecessary parameter to laravel > 5.4.

By Calling `$request->all()` it will add extra parameter in your array which is look like this "master_route/controller/method_of_controller".

Ex: "`admin/mycontroller/updatemethod`".

How to Remove this unnecessary parameter?

Comment: maybe because you are passing that parameter in your `POST`?
can you show your code in your `view` on calling the function.

Comment: Please show your code to obtain this type of error occur.

Comment: Show us your controller and show us what's comming in $request->all().

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to get request data, and you can use one of the below function according to your requirement

1. If you want to get only selected data from request then you can use.It will only get username and password.

   $input = $request->only(['username', 'password']);
2. If you want to get all data except some field then use

   $input = $request->except('credit_card');

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing `update` I am going to guess that you are doing a `PATCH` or `POST` request, in which case you should look up [form request validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation) in the manual.

If my assumption is correct, you should use `$request->validated()` to get only the data that has passed validation. This kills two birds with one stone: You get only the data you need and you make sure the data is valid.

Briefly put code example:

```php
class BlogPostController extends Controller
{
    public function store(UpdateBlogPost $request)
    {
        // Retrieve only the validated input data...
        $validated = $request->validated();
    }
}

class UpdateBlogPost extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'body' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

Now, `$request->validated()` will only contain `title` and `body` and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

try using request()->post() insted of request()->all()